# Yesod: Using typesafe URLs in AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, haskell, yesod

In my Yesod project i have the following route:

```
/api/hide/thread/#Text/#Int      ApiHideThreadR   GET
```

I want to request it on the client side with javascript:

```
function hideThreadCompletely(threadId, board) {
    $.getJSON("/api/hide/thread/"+board+"/"+threadId, function(data) {
        $('#thread-'+threadId).hide();
    });
}
```

But i can't use `@{ApiHideTHreadR}` because Yesod requires it's arguments on compile time. What is the proper solution for this, if i want API URLS to look like `api/board/1/1` and not `api/board?bid=1&tid=1`? Keep using manually-defined URL's like `"/api/hide/thread/"+board+"/"+threadId`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching I found this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yesodweb/LRC-MeqysFg), where it is suggested that you add the url as a "data-url" attribute to some element. And then load the url from the element.
Something like this:

```
<div id="thread-1" data-hide-url=@{ApiHideTHreadR}>

var url = $("#thread-1").data("hide-url")
```

Comment: I still need to specify `ApiHideTHreadR`s arguments, so i don't see how this helps me.

Answer (score 1):

What I always do is get rid of the explicit parameter passing in the route call and instead replace it with :

```
getApiHideThreadR::Handler JSON
getApiHideThreadR = do 
  rawTextParam <- lookupGetParam "text"
  rawThreadId  <- lookupGetParam "table"
  (textParam,threadParam) <- someParseFunction rawTextParam rawThreadId
  ...
```

Then you can use regular ajax style:

```
$.getJSON("@{ApiHideThreadR}",{text:"sometext",tabe:"sometable"},success()...
```

For more complex get to haskell type requests:
https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/wiki/Convert-get-params-into-a-haskell-record

Is a nice template.

Comment: This would make URL to look like `/api/hide/thread?board=1&thread=2`, but i want `/api/hide/thread/1/2`.

Comment: Yeah I knew that, but it also gives you access to the Text field and Int field you were trying to call... I thought that was the main thrust of the question, not getting it to look exactly like the route syntax.  My mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a type-safe route to check at *compile-time* somthing that is known only at *run-time*. I suspect you know this too, but that is the only sense I can make of your question. Thus, your only option is doing it manually.