# Yesod - converting resources to Text urls to be put in a JSON API including query parameters

Tags: haskell, yesod, query-string

The function `getUrlRender` is used for converting `Route (HandlerSite m)` to `Text`, through the use of `Monads`. For instance:

```
routeToText :: MonadHandler m => Route (HandlerSite m) -> m Text
routeToText url = do
  r <- getUrlRender
  return $ r url

getTestR :: Text -> Handler Text
getTestR something = routeToText (TestR something)
```

But what if I want to pass in a query parameter? Could I do it without dealing directly with `Text`s? Another question, could I simplify the type declaration of the function `routeToText`?

I will use these urls to accomplish with a [JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/) regarding pagination, I've created all the abstraction to work with it but I don't know how to implement a way to put a link like `http://example.com/articles?page=2` in a concise way. If there is a even better way to put the link with the query parameter integrating it beautifully with the `Aeson` library without converting it to `Text` first, please, let me know.

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046988/yesod-using-typesafe-urls-in-ajax-calls

Comment: I think you might be best off using [Network.HTTP.Types.URI](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.9/docs/Network-HTTP-Types-URI.html) to generate the query string, then append that to the generated URL.

Comment: You could potentially use the `URI` data type in [`Network.URI`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-uri-2.6.1.0/docs/Network-URI.html) to avoid manipulating `Text`s.