# Haskell - Yesod - print route with placeholder

Tags: haskell, routes, yesod

In my Yesod app I have a route defined as

```
/bookings/#BookingId/review-data BookingReviewDataR GET
```

I need to pass the route to the frontend of the application in such a way that the frontend could call the endpoint for any user defined `BookingId`.

Is there something similar to [`getUrlRender`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.24.4/docs/Yesod-Core-Handler.html#v:getUrlRender) to retrieve from Yesod a string representation of the route with a placeholder instead of a `BookingId`?

Comment: so what should be the outcome, the path with the hash sign (`#`), so `"/bookings/#BookingId/review-data"`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem something like that, yes, or maybe the placeholder could be customised

Comment: Probably a duplicate of my own old question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046988/yesod-using-typesafe-urls-in-ajax-calls